# Xcode 8: Most Swift projects fails to build and compile

Tags: swift

I have upgraded to Xcode 8.2 from Xcode 6 since I haven't been developing for the past few years since the introduction of Swift.
Now, I noticed all the projects I have downloaded from the internet, including Apple's Swift playgrounds and all Swift 2.3 open source projects from Github are all failing to compile.

First I get the error below:

“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

When I fixed it as per the other answers in stackoverflow, which is by setting the value in the property editor to Yes, I get various Swift Compiler errors which are always different for every project, such as:

Value of option unwrapped

Downcast from 'UITableViewCell?' to 'UITableViewCell' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Objective-C method 'parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:' provided by method 'parser(*:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'parser(*:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:)' in protocol 'NSXMLParserDelegate'

Am I doing something wrong? So far I have not been able to run any app aside from a blank tabbed view app I created in Xcode and a very new Swift 3.2 app I downloaded from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. Xcode 8 works only with swift 2.3 or 3.x. and it compile with swift 3 by default. This is the cause of the errors you see.

To compile with swift 2.3, just drop into your project’s build settings and search for legacy swift to find the correct build setting, then switch the setting to YES to opt-in to Swift 2.3 rather than Swift 3.

[image]

You might still get some compilation error, but a lot less due to the smaller difference in swift versions.

The problem is with 3rd party libraries, which must be in the same version of Swift as your project. So, if you're using Swift 2.3, you can't use libraries, that are written in Swift 3.0.

That being said, I do recommend that you stay with swift 3 and fix the errors. It's not that hard since xcode suggests the right syntax in most cases.